# FileZilla error: "The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out" when connecting to ProFTPD

Tags: ftp, amazon-web-services, proftpd

I'm still getting the error after trying the solutions [here](http://www.andrewbrettwatson.com/index.php/homepage/it-solutions/656-two-possible-solutions-to-the-error-the-data-connection-could-not-be-established-etimedout-attempt-timed-out-directory-listing-aborted-by-user-when-connection-via-ftp). Any other ideas how to solve this? I'm using a CentOS 7 server (64bit, x86), on AWS.

Below are the messages from FileZilla.

```
Status: Connecting to XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (54,145,XX,XXX,206,110).
Command:    MLSD
Error:  The data connection could not be established: ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt timed out
```

`54.145.89.103` is not the address I'm trying to connect. My server IP is different. I think it's ProFTPD server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, your FTP server is not correctly configured to announce its external IP address in `PASV` command response.

With ProFTPD server, you need to update the [`MasqueradeAddress` directive](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/modules/mod_core.html#MasqueradeAddress) in `proftpd.conf`.

See also [ProFTPD: Firewalls, Routers, and NAT](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/NAT.html) and *my* article about [network setup for FTP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes).

Comment: you're the man, Martin!